# Batch to copy fonts randomly from one directory to another

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, optimization, copy

I'm scratching my head for more than a week on that. Here is the question:

I have a directory with lots of fonts on my desktop and I want to copy random fonts automatically from the directory into my system windows fonts directory. Additionally, I would like to set some values "from" and "to" into the batch file on how many fonts will be copied, say from 50 to 100 as example. Moreover, some fonts into the directory on my desktop are already exists into windows system fonts directory, so these need to be automatically either overwritten or skipped.
An example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd C:\1
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
copy "!file[%rand%]!" C:\2
```

However this script will copy just one file randomly from directory "1" on C to directory "2". So need to set somehow a range of files (50-100) that need to be copied and solve this overwrite/skip problem if a font is exists into my windows fonts system directory.

After some hours of experiments, the script is able to copy random files from random directories inside some specific location to another one. However, the problem is....it's very slow to copy say 30 files. Maybe someone can help me at least to optimize it? ;)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:loop

pushd "C:\1"

:: Enumerate Files
set "xCount=0"
for /r %%A in (*.*) do if exist "%%~A" set /a "xCount+=1"

:: Select a Random File.
set /a "xIndex=%Random% %% %xCount%"

:: Find an Copy that File
set "xTally=0"
for /r %%A in (*.*) do if exist "%%~A" (
    if "!xTally!" EQU "%xIndex%" (
        xcopy "%%~fA" "C:\2" /Y
        goto End
    )
    set /a "xTally+=1"
)

:End
popd

set /a executecounter=%executecounter%+1
if "%executecounter%"=="30" goto done
goto loop
:done

endlocal
```

Comment: Is this a programming question? Please add the relevant tags.

Comment: And also show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple points in your request that are not clear. First you said that you want to "copy random fonts"; then you specify that you want to set some "from" and "to" values (from 50 to 100 as example) that imply to copy 50 files (but not random ones?). Finally, you want to copy "30 files"!

The Batch file below select "numFiles" files (ie 30) randomly from the range of files that start at "from" (ie 50) and ends at "to" (ie 100), and try to copy them. If the file already exist, it is skipped because you have *not* specified what to do in this case ("either do or not do an action" is *not* a specification!).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Set working values (you may get these values from Batch file parameters)
set numFiles=30
set from=50
set to=100

rem Load the files into an array
cd C:\1
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)

rem Process "numFiles" files
for /L %%i in (1,1,%numFiles%) do (
   rem Create a random index between "from" and "to"
   set /A "rand=((to-from)*!random!)/32768+from"
   rem Pass the new value of "rand" into a FOR parameter
   for %%r in (!rand!) do (
      rem Copy this random file, if not exists
      if not exist "C:\2\!file[%%r]!" copy "!file[%rand%]!" C:\2
   )
)
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have a directory with fonts, say C:\fonts
Inside the directory there are others directories where the funds are sorted alphabetically, like A B C D .. Z.
What I want to do with the batch is to copy fonts randomly from the different directories A-Z to the system fonts directory (%systemroot\fonts).
I want to be able to specify a range number of fonts that batch script will be copying, like from 20 to 30 as example.